# Radeon HD 5800, Ubuntu 11.04, Proprietary Driver installed, graphics not displaying properly

Tags: ati, graphics

I have a Radeon HD 5800 (not sure how to find out which) and I have the proprietary driver installed. I can watch movies, etc, and play some games, but I don't think the 3D part is working properly? I want to play Guild Wars and I've installed it ok, but it doesn't display the log on screen, only the graphics behind it. Wine site says it's platinum and should run fine and to check other games.

Supertuxkart also uses 3D and Wine suggested I test that before "blaming" it, and sure enough it doesn't work. So I'm stumped - I'm not after help running the games so much as how can I make sure my graphics card works properly?

Comment: @Justas you should add that as an answer

Comment: has been done :)

Answer (score 1):

My video card is AMD Radeon HD6470M and I had a problems with proprietary driver on Natty 11.04.

Look attentively through this source and follow an instructions [How to install proprietary driver Catalyst/fglrx](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide).

It's an important for the first to remove previously installed driver before you install Catalyst.

It was very helpful for me, solved my issues with video card and brought 3D